# how to get a class value from text box Webdriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

test condition - to verify the field validation ,i.e if i enter a invalid data in that Text box, then capture the Exception value and verify the same (Please enter first name) so,
following are my HTML code

Before Execution (validation)

```
<input type="text" class="input-txt" data-bind="value: FirstName" id="txtFirstName"
title="Please enter first name" data-orig-title="">
<span class="f-req" style="display: none;"></span>
```

After Execution of Validation

```
<input type="text" class="input-txt ErrorControl" data-bind="value:
FirstName"id="txtFirstName" title="Please enter first name" data-orig-title="">
<span class="f-req" style="">Please enter first name</span>
```

how can verify the validation message if exist or not during invalid entry pass in that object

my code is

```
\\ passing empty value so its thrown an error message
firstname.sendKeys(""); 
\\checking if the "input-txt ErrorControl" class are enabled or not
System.out.println("class name" + firstname.getAttribute("class"));
```

if i execute it always getting "input-txt" class not getting the "input-txt ErrorControl"

Please provide help how to handle this

Thanks

prabu

Answer (score 0):

try to `sendKeys(" ")` of another invalid symbols. And then use this check:

```
webdriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#txtFirstName")).getAttribute("class").contains("ErrorControl")
```

Comment: Thanks for the Replay, i always getting the False , when i Execute it  <br/>Boolean er = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#txtFirstName"))     .getAttribute("class").contains("ErrorControl");  <br/> then i change it as String Like  <br/>String er = driver     .findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name =txtFirstName]"))
.getAttribute("class");  <br/>its produce result as input-txt also not getting that ErrorControl, let me know its required any additionals

Answer (score 0):

```
String Validationmessage = driver.findElement(
    >               By.cssSelector("input#txtFirstName")).getAttribute("title");
```

for the above i will got the validation message for that particular Field